# Preencher INPUTS com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Tenho alguns campos que preciso preencher com AJAX de um SELECT em php.

Já estou conseguindo preencher o campo ID, e CLIENTE, agora falta preencher o restante dos itens, como ENDERECO, CPF, BAIRRO, CIDADE.

**Ajax**

```
$("#resultado").hide();
    $("#cliente").keyup(function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    if($("#cliente").val().length > 2){
     $("#resultado").show();//
     $("#resultado").html("<br><span class='naoEncontrado'>Não encontrado.</span><br><br><span><a onClick='novoCliente(1);'>(+) Cadastrar Novo </a></span>");
     document.getElementById("resultado").style = "height:auto;  margin-top:45px; width:330;";
     $.ajax({       
         type: "POST",
          url: "busca_cliente.php",
         data: {q:query},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(json){
            var options = "";
            $.each(json, function(key, value){


     options +="<a class='resultado_json' alt='" + value + "' id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</a><br/>";
                     //"<option value='" + key + "'> " + value + "</option>";
                });


$("#resultado").show();
    $("#resultado").html("<br>"+options+"<br><span><a onClick='novoCliente(1);'>(+) Cadastrar Novo</a></span>");

  $(".resultado_json").click(function(){
   var codigo_p = $(this).attr('id');
   var nome_p = $(this).attr('alt');
   $("#id_cliente").val(codigo_p);
   $("#cliente").val(nome_p);
   $("#resultado").hide();
   $("#resultado").html('');
   });
     }
  });
  }else{
      $("#resultado").hide();
      $("#resultado").html('');
      $("#id_cliente").val(0);
      }    
    });
```

**busca_cliente.php**

```
    <?php
$consulta = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID,NOME FROM cliente WHERE (NOME LIKE '$cliente' OR CNPJ_CPF LIKE '$cliente')");

$consulta->execute();
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta
    //$idCliente[] = $linha['ID'];
    //$nomeCliente[] = $linha['NOME'];
    $retorno[ $linha['ID'] ] =  $linha['NOME'];
    //echo "<a href='#' name='$nomeCliente' id='$idCliente' class='procura'>$nomeCliente</a><br/>";
    }

echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
?>
```

INPUTS QUE RECEBEM A MODIFICAÇÃO

```
    <input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente">
    <input type="text" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente">
    <input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco">
    <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade">
    <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep">

<div id="resultado_ajax"></div>
```

Comment: Olá Alh! E qual é o problema que está acontecendo?

Comment: Olá @DvD, estou preenchendo o input CLIENTE e ID, com ajax vindo do php, agora falta preencher mais INPUTS como cidade, endereco desse mesmo modo.

Comment: Mas tá dando algum erro?

Comment: @DvD não, esta funcionando porem só preenche o input Cliete e Id_cliente, preciso preencher os outros inputs restantes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua `query` do `mysql` está buscando apenas `ID,NOME`, para que ela retorne mais resultados precisa inseri-los a sua busca ou usar um coringa `*` que retorne todos estes dados, exemplo troca a sua consulta:

```
"SELECT ID,NOME FROM cliente WHERE ..."
```

Por

```
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE ... //para retornar todas as colunas do banco
```

ou por esta que retorne apenas as colunas que deseja

```
SELECT ID,NOME,CEP,LOGRADOURO,ETC...,ETC... FROM cliente WHERE ...
```

E no while você precisa preencher o `array` que será retornado via `json`

```
$retorno[] = array( 'ID' => $linha['ID'] , 'NOME' => $linha['NOME'], 'CEP' => $linha['CEP'], <assim até satisfazer> );
```

Na parte `html` você precisa ajustar a sua necessidade.

> Considerações do seu código

Ele está pegando o resultado da tag `<a` que pertence a classe  `resultado_json` e lá tem o atributo `alt` que está recebendo o valor referente a chave `key`, e o atributo `id` pertencente a mesma classe que recebe o valor da `chave`

> No php você definiu que o `array` terá como chave `$retorno[ $linha['ID']`, e o valor sendo `=  $linha['NOME'];`

- Dessa forma a contrução de array ficou assim:

  ```
  $retorno('chave' => 'valor')
  ```

E como só está retornando na consulta estes dois dados sempre será o mesmo resultado, se analisar na resposta verá que mudei a forma do array pra retornar uma coleção de chaves, ficando dessa forma:

```
$retorno(
'ID' => 'VALOR_ID',
'NOME' => 'VALOR_NOME',
'CEP' => 'VALOR_CEP',
...
'COLUNA_BD' => 'VALOR_COLUNA'
);
```

> Agora no `each` do `json`, temos alumas observações:

- Ele está retornando os dados para um link `<a>`

  ```
  <a class='resultado_json' alt='" + value + "' id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</a>
  ```

Que sempre irá receber o mesmo `key` e o mesmo `value` pois foi definido desta forma no array do `php`

Para contornar esse problema você deve mudar a forma de retornar estes dados.

__No `success` do `json` você criar os resultados desta forma

```
success: function(json){
$('#id_cliente').val(json.ID);
$('#cliente').val(json.NOME);
$('#cep').val(json.CEP);
$('#rg').val(json.RG);
}
```

Ou seja `$('#<nome_id_input>')` e `.val(json.Nome)` se refere a chave setada no `array do php`

Aqui vou alterar o `array do php` para que seja mais fácil para entender.

```
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$retorno['ID'] = (string) $linha['ID'];
$retorno['NOME'] = (string) $linha['NOME'];
$retorno['CEP']  = (string) $linha['CEP'];
$retorno['RG']  = (string) $linha['RG'];
}
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Olá, e no json lá onde estou pegando o CLIENTE e ID_CLIENTE , não sei bem se é só pegar os dados pois me pareceu que está setado para pegar pelo (id, e alt) var codigo_p = $(this).attr('id');
   var nome_p = $(this).attr('alt');

Comment: aqui nessa linha também me parece estar pegando pelo key (alt) e value (id)

Comment: Estou tentando entender o seu código javascript mas o each tem apenas um resultado e sequencia seguinte está confusa, você da hide e depois apaga o conteudo `html(' ')`?

Comment: Não precisa olhar para isso, pois ele tem outra funcao que é retornar o resultado dos dados do select com os resultado dos clientes cadastrados, mas ele não esta pertencendo a essa função desta dúvida da pergunta em questão.

Comment: Editei a resposta e expliquei passo a passo a forma de solucionar o problema, mas como não conheço a sua base de dados usei nomes genéricos precisa se atentar sobre os nome corretos e se estão iguais, `case sensitive`

Comment: Valeu amigão, consegui aqui com sua ajuda!! É de pessoas assim que esse fórum precisa, obrigado!